# Configure Cognito User Pool Domain using Terraform + Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, cloudflare

My problem is how to configure Cognito User Pool Domain using Terraform + Cloudflare

From [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_domain), I see that

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "auth-cognito-A" {
  name    = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main.domain
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = false

    name    = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main.cloudfront_distribution
    zone_id = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main.cloudfront_distribution_zone_id
  }
}
```

I tried this Terraform Cloudflare config:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "bmj_cognito_cname" {
  zone_id = "zoneid"
  name    = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.bmj_user_pool_domain.domain
  type    = "CNAME"
  value   = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.bmj_user_pool_domain.cloudfront_distribution
  ttl     = 300 
}
```

And I got this error:

```
│ Error: creating Cognito User Pool Domain (user.exampledomain.com): InvalidParameterException: Custom domain is not a valid subdomain: Was not able to resolve the root domain, please ensure an A record exists for the root domain.
│ 
│   with aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.bmj_user_pool_domain,
│   on aws_cognito.tf line 71, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "bmj_user_pool_domain":
│   71: resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "bmj_user_pool_domain" {
│ 
╵
```

What should I do to solve this issue?